# cordova can't find android build tools on windows xp

Tags: android, cordova

I recently installed cordova and recent version of android sdk(24.1.2),and Because of Iran sanctions! I can't download android build tools with Android SDK Manager.therefore I downloaded it(v.22) as a zip file and extracted it to "android-tools" directory in my "android-sdk" directory.but cordova can't find it and when I build the app,it gives me this error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version
 19.1.0 or higher.
```

p.n:I have added "tools" and "platform-tools" directories path to System Variables.

I have downloaded `sdk build tools r.20` but have same problem. and an another weird thing is that `Android SDK Manager` has problem with `renderscript` and `lib` directories that are in `build-tools` directory, as showed in pic:[image]

#### Update

I solved it :) I created a folder with name `22` into `build-tools` folder and copied all files into it and it works.

Comment: What is the `target SDK` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? I think it is 19 and that SDK is required for building. In-case you're fine with keeping the target as 22, you could edit your `AndroidManifest.xml` for `android:targetSdkVersion` as 22 and re-try.

Comment: Thanks Keval,but the `target SDK` is 22.

Comment: Have you set ANDROID_HOME also?

Comment: yes,I set it as my `android-sdk` directory.

Comment: What you have copied in the `22` folder you have created ? @Saeed Noori

Comment: @Pappu : all files that are in `build-tools` directory.

Answer (score 3):

What I realized is that I'd installed a latest RC revision of build tools - 23 rc3 (in Tools (Preview Channel) visible in the SDK GUI) and perhaps the cordova.gradle build script wasn't accepting it because of the way its REGEX is written/created. The folder was named 23.0.0_rc3 in the $(SDK)\build-tools directory and the function for finding build-tools was most probably ignoring it. Here is the function from cordova.gradle:

```
String[] getAvailableBuildTools() {
    def buildToolsDir = new File(getAndroidSdkDir(), "build-tools")
    buildToolsDir.list()
        .findAll { it ==~ /[0-9.]+/ }
        .sort { a, b -> compareVersions(b, a) }
}
```

When I installed a non-RC revision of build tools, it just worked fine.